# I want to specify the app overall font size in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to specify the font size of the entire app, just like the code below specifies the font type for the entire app.

```
  theme: ThemeData(

    fontFamily: Q,
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
  ),
```

make it a global variable,

```
int fontsize = 20;
```

Is there any other way to do it this way? Is there any other way?

```
Style: TextStyle(
              Color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: fontsize,
)
```

Comment: you can make a file named constant and declare it as static const int fontsize = 20;

Answer (score 0):

The font family can be the same throught the app if you want it, however you can't set a single value for all the font sizes of your app. There are different sizes for different occasions e.g :

```dart
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      //headlines
      headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 72.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      // titles
      headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
      // bodies of text
      bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontFamily: 'Hind'),
    ),
```